# Numpy Broadcasting multidimentional arrays while trying to build a boolean mask

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, mask, array-broadcasting

I am facing a problem while building a boolean mask on a three-dimensional numpy array.
The array can be imagined as follows, for example as an array with shape (18,2,7) containing random numbers:

```
import random
import numpy as np

a = np.array([[[random.random() for i in range(7)] for j in range(2)] for k in range(18)])
```

And a predefined boolean Mask with shape (18,2,1)

```
x = np.zeros((18,2,1), dtype="bool")
```

Important: **I cannot change the variable definition here and have to work with this shape.**

I would like to iterate over the a and create a x mask where True if the value in a is less than 0.5.

Here is my attempt so far:

[image]

I also tried by just adding the elements directly into the array but got a broadcasting error. Is there a way for the array to expand "automatically" creating the map that i need?

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the shape of `a`:

```
In [22]: a.shape
Out[22]: (18, 2, 7)
```

Incidentally a more direct way of generating the same size random array:

```
In [23]: a=np.random.random_sample((18,2,7))

In [24]: x = np.zeros((18,2,1), dtype="bool")
```

Your loop(s) test all elements of `a`, as in:

```
In [25]: (a<0.5).shape
Out[25]: (18, 2, 7)
```

For a given `i,j`, your `knum` is a 7 element list.  What the error is telling you is that it can't put 7 elements in toe `x[i,j]` slot, which only holds one item.

Numpy arrays don't "expand automatically".  You can create a

```
x = np.zeros((18,2,7), dtype="bool")
```

Or you could somehow the reduce the last dimension of (18,2,7) to 1, such as with an `any` or `all`.

Comment: Thanks for the response and help me to writing it in a better way!